# ImageProcessor with EPiServer not working

Tags: episerver, imageprocessor, episerver-9

I am trying to configure an EPiServer 9 site with [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) but can't get it to work.

I have installed the following nuget packages:

```
ImageProcessor
ImageProcessor.Web
ImageProcessor.Web.Config
```

With the default configuration nothing happens. With the following custom configuration in config/imageprocessor/security.config ...

```
<security>
  <services>
    <service name="CloudImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.CloudImageService, ImageProcessor.Web">
      <settings>
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="8194304" />
        <setting key="Timeout" value="30000" />
        <setting key="Host" value="http://site.local/globalassets/"/>
      </settings>
    </service>
    <service prefix="remote.axd" name="RemoteImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.RemoteImageService, ImageProcessor.Web">
      <settings>
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="4194304" />
        <setting key="Timeout" value="3000" />
        <setting key="Protocol" value="http" />
      </settings>
      <whitelist>
      </whitelist>
    </service>
  </services>
</security>
```

... it seems like ImageProcessor is trying to resize my image but I get below error ...

```
[ImageFormatException: Input stream is not a supported format.]
   ImageProcessor.ImageFactory.Load(Stream stream) +523
   ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.<ProcessImageAsync>d__34.MoveNext() +3308
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +162
```

... when trying to resize an image to 200px width like this:

http://site.local/globalassets/sample_image.jpg?width=200

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this to work? The image is showing as normal without the width parameter:

http://site.local/globalassets/sample_image.jpg

Comment: There is a good blog post on getting ImageProcessor working with Episerver: https://world.episerver.com/blogs/vincent-baaij/dates/2017/10/episerver-and-imageprocessor-more-choice-for-developers-and-designers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In projects where I've used EPiServer with ImageProcessor I have always had to create my own IImageService.

Something like this:

https://gist.github.com/andreas-cloudnine/34dc468205a230f0579585db17aa1593

The ImageFile used is the media type in your project that inherits from EPiServer.Core.ImageData.

Then you have to use it in web.config as well, just replace the entire  section with this configuration:

```
<security>
  <services>
    <service name="EPiServerImageService" type="YourSite.EPiServerImageService, YourSite" />
</services>
</security>
```

Comment: Nice! Never seen anyone using ImageProcessor with EPiServer before.

Comment: I've tried to add my own IImageService like your exampel. Where and how should I add it to my web.config? Could you please add example of your added row(s) in web.config? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated my answer with configuration. Please accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get it to work. I now get a NullReferenceException in
`ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule.GetImageServiceForRequest(String url, String applicationPath)`

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot... I implemented EPiServer.ImageLibrary.IImageService instead of ImageProcessor version. Thank you so much for the help!